# Phantom binary installed with curl

Tags: curl, youtube-dl

I upgraded binary `youtube-dl` following [this instruction](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html). `locate` seems to find it, not `ls`, and it cannot be invoked. What is happening?

```
/usr/bin $ sudo apt-get remove youtube-dl
/usr/bin $ sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
/usr/bin $ sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
/usr/bin $ locate youtube-dl
/usr/bin/youtube-dl
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/youtube-dl
/usr/share/doc/youtube-dl
/usr/share/man/man1/youtube-dl.1.gz
/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions/_youtube-dl
/var/lib/dpkg/info/youtube-dl.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/youtube-dl.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/youtube-dl.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/youtube-dl.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/youtube-dl.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/youtube-dl.prerm
/usr/bin $ youtube-dl --version
bash: /usr/bin/youtube-dl: No such file or directory
/usr/bin $ ls y*
yacc  ybmtopbm  yelp  yes  yuvsplittoppm  yuvtoppm
```

Comment: look at the curl  command line in your printout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You downloaded with curl to `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl` and have removed the old version from `/usr/bin`. `locate` is not up to date. Run `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`.

Comment: `/local` eluded me, that and your answer explains most of it. `/usr/bin $ sudo updatedb
[sudo] password for er:         
er@laptop /usr/bin $ locate youtube-dl
/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
/var/lib/dpkg/info/youtube-dl.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/youtube-dl.postrm`

Answer (score 1):

`locate` is not "real time" : it scans the filesystem and remembers files and  locations in its internal database.
This is what's happening to you here when running :

```
/usr/bin/youtube-dl
```

You're served the outdated value of this file's location because the database has not (yet) been updated.
You can force this with :

```
slocate -u
```

full details : https://ss64.com/bash/locate.html